# Anchor (hash) event handler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a double post but I haven't found any suitable solved problem that looks like mine. I have a webpage that shows a list of entries and a link "Add an Entry" that redirects to page.html#addEntry. When I click "Add an Entry" a little form should show up (display none -> block) and let the user fill in the entry info. I don't want to use an "onclick" event because I need to be able to redirect users directly to page.html#addEntry and let them see the "Add Entry" form directly.

I have seen this in other websites, I am sure it is possible to launch an event "onAnchorChange" but I can't seem to find how. Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: I guess you mean `onhashchange` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange

Comment: YES ! Oh my god I'm so lame ! I couldn't think of the word "hash"...

Comment: Actualy... no. What do I do if hash was never changed but it was there from the beggining ?

Comment: `$(window).on('load hashchange', function(){...});` would fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use the 'hashchange' listener like so:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aph3bf8d/1/)

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    $(location.hash).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Hope this helps, let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes this is a good step towards my solution. Now how do I do if I want my users to directly see the form if they get directly to the URL page.html#addEntry ?

Comment: Nevermind. I added a hash-checking script on pageload. Thank you for your answer. Sometimes I just turn my brain off...

Comment: No problem. Any other questions?